# Raspberry Pi not connecting to WiFi while using Raspbian but does when using LibreElec

Tags: raspbian, wifi

So my Raspberry Pi worked pretty well for 2-3 months but suddenly it stops connecting to WiFi. The WiFi symbol gradually turns blue and white, as it does while connecting to a network but that's it. No internet connectivity. This problem is only for Raspbian. I'm able to connect to WiFi when I'm using Libre ELEC. What might be causing this issue and how should I solve it?

Ps. Additional information if it helps, the date and time are too off. And I'm unable to set it as I'm unable to connect to the internet in the very first place.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it connecting to the right network? click on the wifi symbol and check.

Comment: I tried lot of systems on my rasp B3+ ( centos / raspbian / ubuntu ) and yes even if I m configuring it manually using the nmtui I m still having issue using ssh due to lost packets, it connects then disconnects , I m using cable RJ and this seems the only way ( I did all needed updates, but there is no success )